# Procedural displacement doesn't look right, it's very shiny and strange looking. - BlenderGuru's donut tutorial

Tags: displacement

I'm sorry for the bad explanation, I don't really know how to describe it, but after doing the procedural displacement step, my donut looks almost shiny and not quite right. Does anyone have a solution? [image: Donut]

[image: Node]

Comment: Hello :). Your displacement is set to 1 cm, and SSS to 10 cm. Both should be in the milimeter range. Whether it looks *not quite right* is a matter of opinion :).

Comment: Thank you, this is much better.